# Creating and listing an array from separate functions

Tags: c, arrays

I was asked to define a function `array_print()` that takes in two arguments:

- `int *ptr` represents a pointer to an array of integers
- `int array` represents the size of the array

and that lists the elements of an array without returning any values;

A function `array_create()` that takes one argument:

- `int array` represents the size of the array

and returns a pointer to this array;
I need to call this function inside `main()` to create an array and the call `array_print()` to print its elements.

#### This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX  100
#define SIZE  10

void array_print(int *ptr, int array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array; i++){
        printf("Value of array[%d] is %d",i, *ptr);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int* array_create(int array) {
    int *t = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        t[i] = rand() % MAX;
    }
    return t;
}

int main() {
  int *t = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

  array_create(SIZE);
  array_print(t, SIZE);
  free(t);
  return 0;
}
```

I should get in the output random elements in the interval (0, MAX), but instead I get this.

```
Value of array[0] is 0
Value of array[1] is 0
Value of array[2] is 0
Value of array[3] is 0
Value of array[4] is 0
Value of array[5] is 0
Value of array[6] is 0
Value of array[7] is 0
Value of array[8] is 0
Value of array[9] is 0
```

Could someone correct my code so that it outputs random elements instead of 0.

Comment: Were you asked to ignore the size passed to your function and allocate 10 elements regardless? Don't think so.

Comment: @n.m. Where in OP's code does he ignore the size passed into a function and always allocate 10 elements?

Comment: @GovindParmar `array_create`.

Comment: @n.m. Ah you’re right, didn’t see that parameter. That can be omitted entirely though since adjusting the macro `SIZE` will change the amount allocated and the amount processed by `array_print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. You call `malloc` both in `main` and `array_create`. In `main`, all you need is:

   ```
   int *t = array_create(SIZE);
   ```
2. In `array_print`, you are always dereferencing the first element in the array. This will do:

   ```
   printf("Value of array[%d] is %d\n",i, ptr[i]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you have to increment your pointer, otherwise you will repeat the first value of ptr n times.

```
void array_print(int *ptr, int array) {
for (int i = 0; i < array; i++){
    printf("Value of array[%d] is %d",i, *ptr); // should be printf("Value of array[%d] is %d",i, ptr[i]);
    printf("\n");

int main() {
  int *t = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int)); // why are you creating your array again in main?

  array_create(SIZE);
  array_print(t, SIZE);
  free(t);
  return 0;
}
```

Full working code example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define MAX  100
    #define SIZE  10

void array_print(int *ptr, int array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array; i++) {
        printf("Value of array[%d] is %d", i, ptr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int* array_create(int array) {
    int *t = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        t[i] = rand() % MAX;
    }
    return t;
}

int main() {
    int *ptr = array_create(SIZE);
    array_print(ptr, SIZE);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. If an array is allocated on the heap (i.e. with `malloc`), it will persist beyond the lifetime of its scope.

Comment: @GovindParmar Thank you for pointing that out. I haven't personally used C in quite a while and seem to have forgotten a few things. I'll edit my answer accordingly.